# libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found

Tags: upgrade, glibc

When importing a library (cdms2) in python, I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /usr/local/uvcdat/1.3.1/Externals/lib/libcurl.so.4)
```

My version of libc6 is currently 2.15 (Ubuntu 12.04). My understanding is that the newest version is not in a stable repository: how can I force apt to update to version 2.16?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a much safer way to run a single app. Problem is: while glibc is meant to be backwards-compatible, it is not 100% accurate. Issues are known. So, do not update the library system-wide. Instead, prepare a whole set of updated libraries. Put them in, say, */catbed*. Then just run

```
   /catbed/ld-linux.so.3 --library-path=/catbed:/whatever-else /usr/bin/python -python-args
```

Of cause, adapt the filenames to your case. This is much safer way to go, because if you mess up your system *ld-linux+libc* pair you will not be able to fix it from inside the OS. You will have hard times even chrooting into it then. 
I routinely use the trick for old proprietary Linuxes (gcc 3.1, kernel 2.3) on which I want to run Qt5.

Answer (score 0):

> Was the  UVCDAT installation manually built one or downloaded the
>   pre-built binaries ?

Binaries of UVCDAT 1.3.1 were built on Ubuntu 13.04 platform .  Even if you solve this one, could come across many other errors. Try downloading [UVCDAT 1.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdat/files/Releases/UV-CDAT/1.2/).   If you want the latest UVCDAT and want to stick to 12.04 try building from the source code.  Else upgrade OS to 13.04 and use the latest UVCDAT 1.4.1.