# Nagios remote execution problem libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found

Tags: 12.04, glibc, nagios3

i have installed nagios core 4 on ubuntu server 12.04 lts..
everything working fine,, but... i have a problem with remote command to a remote linux (ubuntu server 12.04) pc!
when i try to check a service, for example: check_swap, check_disk etc.. i got everytime an error:

```
Remote command execution failed: /home/nagios/plugins/check_disk: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/nagios/plugins/check_disk)
```

the remote pc is not my pc and i don't want to make a disaster! :)
So... how can i fix this problem?
any help be appreciate!!! ;)
thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Also see [this answer - libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found#421795)

Comment: Thank you for reply bain! :) in this particular case yes.. these two servers are both 64 bit..
i use 64bit-nagios-plugins for 64bit servers (remote servers) and 32bit-nagios-plugins for 32bit servers (remote servers)....the authorized_keys access and  the check_by_ssh pointing to the specific plugin (check_disk etc...) working fine with my other servers.... only in this i got this error :(
there isn't no way for fix this error? for example update only to the glibc 2.14?
anyway thank you for your time and your help!

Comment: Try the answer I linked to for only updating libc.

Comment: i resolved with the downgrade of the plugins! thank you for the support! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not just take a binary compiled on one Linux system and run it on another, unless they have exactly the same architecture and libraries. In this case, the remote system is complaining that the the C library that your compiled binary requires (glibc 2.14) is not present. You need to either:

- Build nagios on the remote server so that it gets compiled and linked against its libraries
- If both local and remote are the same arch (i386 or amd64) do `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` on both, then reboot, then recompile nagios. Since both will thehn have an up-to-date Ubuntu 12.04 on same arch, they will have the same libraries, and you can use the same binaries between them.